# How can I show a traffic device modes?

Tags: icons, interface

I'm developing a software and need to show my device (a signal light controller) modes. The device may be in smart mode (automatically controlling signals based on sensors data and advanced algorithms) or blinking mode (blinking yellow lights usually at night when there is no traffic).

For pre-time mode I show a `clock` and I think it's to the point.
For smart mode I think a `gear` is a good idea. And also a `stop sign` for blinking mode.

Comment: Unfortunately [icon requests](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/1392/4679) are off topic for this site. Revise your question to make it on topic. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Smart Mode: Show a full signal light (Red, Yellow, Green all on)
- Blink mode: Signal light with Yellow light on and red/green grayed out? (Don't blink the yellow light -- it will be distracting!)

Comment: +1 simple, obvious, directly related to the domain. I like it a lot.

Comment: I've designed this idea in Photoshop and the result is very good. Thanks.